# custom searchResultsTableView

Tags: ios

I am looking to have custom `UITableViewCells` for my `UISearchDisplayController`. The `searchResultsTableView` is a readonly property. I have the delegate and datasource for the searchviewcontroller returning the custom cells, however, it seems to still be using the `searchResultsTableView` cells. What's the best way to have the search results using my own `UITableViewCells`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a search begins, a whole new UITableView is created.  This new table view will use default settings and won't match your table view. In your UISearchDisplayDelegate, override searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch: in order to re-theme the new UITableView, like this:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    // Re-style the search controller's table view
    UITableView *tableView = controller.searchResultsTableView;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can have it use the UITableViewCells that my delegate/datasource are returning? I don't want to modify just the properties.

Comment: The tableView created for search will (should?) already be using your existing delegate/datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but it sounds like you want two different `UITableViewCell` types (subclasses?) to be returned when you're typing a search, or when you're not searching. Is that right?

Like John said, and depending on how you hooked up the `UISearchDisplayController`, both the search results table view and your default table view will fire `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCellForRowAtIndexPath`. In those methods you can check which tableView is asking for the cell and customize it as necessary. I customize the background, text and color of my cells and this approach works well for me. I can post code if you'd like.